# NMAKE : fatal error U1077: return code '0x2'

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libsvm, nmake

I am trying to build **libsvm** binary for Windows. But nmake returns an error code.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\libsvm-3.23>nmake -f Makefile.win clean all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.14.26433.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

    erase /Q *.obj windows\*.exe windows\*.dll windows\*.exp windows\*.lib
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\Desktop\libsvm-3.23\*.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\Desktop\libsvm-3.23\windows\*.exe
    cl.exe /nologo /O2 /EHsc /I. /D _WIN64 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -c sv
m.cpp
svm.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\include\vcruntime.h(180): error C2371: 'size_t': redefinition;different basic types
 predefined C++ types (compiler internal)(16): note: see declaration of 'size_t'
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.14.26428\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

C:\Users\user\Desktop\libsvm-3.23>
```

What is the wrong with this?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2842ba6a-946f-45e2-8a86-d88831d85154/sizet-redefinition-different-basic-types?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: It looks like you are building the project as 64 bit while the lib you use is 32 bit. Drop the _WIN64 option from the compiler options

Comment: @FaisalM bro, how?